# AddDays from DateTimePicker and Show it again into DateTimePicker VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, datetime

I have 1 textbox and 1 datetimepicker.
The textbox is to count how many days that I want to add.

Then when I'm lostfocus from the textbox, the datetimepicker will add the new value which is plus from the textbox.

This is how I'm doing but I've got nothing:

```
Dim waktu As Integer = pengerjaan_tb.Text
Dim datex As DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(
pengerjaan_dtp.Text, "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
datex.AddDays(5)
MsgBox(datex)
pengerjaan_dtp.Value = datex.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
```

I show it in msgbox but the date is not renew with the new value. How could this be happening? What have I done wrong?

Comment: Consider using a [NumericUpDown](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57dy4d56(v=vs.110).aspx) control instead of a TextBox to input the number of days to add.  Then you can set a minimum and maximum value and you won't have to parse the value to convert it to an integer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Couple of things:

1. `DateTimePicker` has a `Value` property that is of type `DateTime`. You are using this property to set a value to the `DateTimePicker`, but you don't use it to **get** the value from the `DateTimePicker`.
2. `DateTime` is Immutable. This means that `AddDays` does not change the value of the current instance of the `DateTime` struct, but returning a new instance of `DateTime` instead.

Try this instead:

```
Dim waktu As Integer = Integer.Parse(pengerjaan_tb.Text) 
pengerjaan_dtp.Value = pengerjaan_dtp.Value.AddDays(waktu)
```

Answer (score 3):

First, turn on `Option Strict`:

```
Dim waktu As Integer = pengerjaan_tb.Text
```

This is implicitly converting Text to integer.  Option Strict converts potential runtime exceptions into compiler errors.

There is no need to parse the contents of a `DateTimePicker`, the value property will be a `DateTime` type.  Then, `DateTime` types are immutable - the `AddDays` method returns a *new* `DateTime` with the new value:

```
Dim datex As DateTime = pengerjaan_dtp.Value
pengerjaan_dtp.Value = datex.AddDays(5)
```